# Isekai manga where the main character tries to live in a jungle, in a cave, and has the ability to create golems

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The manga is about a kid trying to live his life in the wilderness. He has the ability to create mini-golems and then, later, he creates a golem out of mithril and a nearby kingdom tries to exploit the resources of the jungle.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Just to clarify, did the MC create a single golem out of mithril, or more than one?

Comment: When you return, you can accept your self-answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 1):

*[Isekai Ni Otosareta… Jouka Wa Kihon!](https://isekai.fandom.com/wiki/Isekai_ni_Otosareta%E2%80%A6_Jouka_wa_Kihon!)*

> One day, a dull young man from Japan gets caught up in a heroic summoning and goes to another world. The next time he wakes up, he's not in a castle with a king, but in a deep forest since the summoning failed! You'd think he'd be at a loss, but he starts living a life of survival with a positive attitude that doesn't involve deep thought!
>
> Then, before he knows it, he saves the cursed forest and magical beasts one after another with his magical powers, and is befriended by wolves and dogs in a healing paradise! However, he doesn't realize that they are actually legendary demonic beasts and spirits at all. What's more, that they are adored! A positive young man unknowingly plays with the legendary magical beasts, a heartwarming and misunderstood fantasy begins!

He created 10 small golem at first at chapter 8, and [the TV Tropes entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/IsekaiNiOtosaretaJoukaWaKihon) mentions that normally mages can control no more than three as well as that he can manipulate mythril and orichalcum, substances normally highly resistant to magic.

Comment: Hi, it's great that you found it.  Is it possible to provide any links to a summary?

Comment: We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.